# MySQL syntax ERROR, I simply don't see where

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am having a syntax error with an sql statement I am executing but for the life of me I can't find any error.

I have created my own database class with functionality to make prepared statements and execute them, I don't think there is a problem with my implementation as I have never had any issues with it before now. But, just in case there is a problem there I am going to show the code for that too.

Prepare:

```
public function prepare($index, $sql) {
    if(isset(self::$PS[$index])){
        $ermsg = "Index [$index] is already in use.";
        throw new Exception($ermsg, 1);
    }
    try{
        self::$PS[$index] = $this->dbh->prepare($sql);
    }
    catch(PDOException $e){
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

and execute:

```
public function execute($index, Array $param = array()) {
    if(!isset(self::$PS[$index])){
        $ermsg = "Index [$index] is unavailable.";
        throw new Exception($ermsg, 1);
    }

    foreach($param as $key => $val){
        if(is_int($key)) ++$key;

        $type = $this->getValueType($val);

        $bnd = self::$PS[$index]->bindValue($key, $val, $type);

        if(!$bnd){
            $ermsg = "Paramater '$key' in [$index] failed to bind";
            throw new Exception($ermsg, 2);
        }

    }

    try{
        $bnd = self::$PS[$index]->execute();
    }
    catch(PDOException $e){
        $ermsg = "PDO-Error while executing prepared statement [$index] ".$e->getMessage();
        throw new Exception($ermsg, 3);
    }

    if($bnd === false){
        $ermsg = "Result error in prepared statement [$index]";
        throw new Exception($ermsg, 3);
    }

    return self::$PS[$index];
}
```

As I mentioned, I have never experienced issues using this so I don't think it's the problem, but who knows.

Now my implementation:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO ratings (course_id, overall, design, condition, service, value, rated_by, date_rated) 
      VALUES (:course_id, :overall, :design, :condition, :service, :value, :rated_by, now()))";

  DBH::getInstance()->prepare('rateit', $sql);


      $stmt = DBH::getInstance()->execute('rateit', array(
          ":course_id"=>$course_id,
          ":overall"=>$overall,
          ":design"=>$design,
          ":condition"=>$condition,
          ":service"=>$service,
          ":value"=>$value,
          ":rated_by"=>$log_user_id
      ));
  }
  if($stmt) {
      echo 'suc, Thanks! Your ratings have been added to the course.';
      exit();
  }else{
      echo 'err, There was an error rating the course. Please try again later';
      exit();
  }
```

This is the exact syntax error message I receive:

> Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'condition, service, value, rated_by, date_rated) VALUES (1, 5, 5, 5, 5, 3, '18',' at line 1'

If someone can spot my syntax error, or maybe find something else wrong that would be causing this that would be awesome. Thanks for any help.

Comment: `condition` is a reserved word in MySQL. You can either change the column name, or quote it using backticks.

Comment: It also looks like you have an extra ')' near `now()`.

Comment: Have a look to this: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1563146/1267304

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Condition is a [reserved word](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/keywords.html) in MySQL. That could be it.

According to [9.2 Schema Object Names](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/identifiers.html), to use reserved words as identifiers they must be quoted. Use backticks or, with enabled [ANSI_QUOTES](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_ansi_quotes) SQL mode, double quotation marks. Quoting is not necessary if the reserved word follows a period in a qualified name.

Answer (score 3):

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO ratings (course_id, overall, design, condition, service, value, rated_by, date_rated) 
  VALUES (:course_id, :overall, :design, :condition, :service, :value, :rated_by, now()))";
```

Should be:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO ratings (course_id, overall, design, `condition`, service, value, rated_by, date_rated) 
  VALUES (:course_id, :overall, :design, :condition, :service, :value, :rated_by, now())";
```

Comment: You need to quote out `condition`, too.

Comment: Look at `now()))` in the fist example and `now())` in the second.  There is an extra ')'.

Comment: Square braces?  Are you sure `[:condition]` is the right syntax?

Comment: Square braces is in sql-server in mysql is backticks

Comment: @Brian - the `:condition` in the values is fine - it's the column name that needs escaping.

Comment: I think it's the `condition` in the list of field names that needs to be fixed.  With backticks.  I don't think `:condition` is a problem (`':condition'` is incorrect).

Comment: Well-spotted, @Brian.

Answer (score 3):

`Condition` is a reserved word in MySQL. You should always use backticks ("`") in `table` and `column` names to avoid errors like that. Also looks like you have an extra `)` at the end of the sql query

[List of Reserved Words](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysqld-version-reference/en/mysqld-version-reference-reservedwords-5-5.html)